# Manejar tabla dentro de otra tabla html sin que interfiera en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una tabla con `id=mytabla`, la cual dentro lleva varios datos, y en la última fila un campo llamado retenciones que deberia mostrar otra tabla dentro, en esto no tengo inconvenientes, quedando asi:

```
<table id="mytabla" class="table table-sm table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th id="#">#</th>
            <th id="Documento" class="tb-gra">Documento</th>
            <th id="Fecha">Fecha(emision)</th>
            <th id="retenciones">Retenciones</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
            <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
            <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
            <td>SIN RETENCION</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
            <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
            <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
            <td>SIN RETENCION</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
            <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
            <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>IVA</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>120.00</td>
                            <td>100.0</td>
                            <td>120.00</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

En **JavaScript** quiero seleccionar la tabla y contar las filas, pero tambien me cuenta las de la segunda tabla, como hago para que no cuente la segunda tabla o no la tome en cuenta, utilizo este código:

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytabla");
var fila=document.getElementById("mytabla").getElementsByTagName('tr');
var row=table.insertRow(parseInt(fila.length);
var cantidaddefilas=fila.length;
```

Pero me esta contando las de la segunda tabla, como hago para que no cuente esas.

Comment: prueba poniendole otro id a esa segunda tabla

Comment: ¿Por qué una tabla dentro de otra tabla? No es recomendable desde el punto de vista de las buenas prácticas. No es en vano que hay categorías de elementos y contenedores en HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtenerlo mediante la propiedad **[`rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows)** de la tabla referenciada por su id.

```js
var theTable = document.getElementById("mytabla");
var rowCount = theTable.rows.length;
console.log(rowCount);
```

```html
<table id="mytabla" class="table table-sm table-striped">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th id="#">#</th>
                <th id="Documento" class="tb-gra">Documento</th>
                <th id="Fecha">Fecha(emision)</th>
                <th id="retenciones">Retenciones</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
                <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
                <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
                <td>SIN RETENCION</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
                <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
                <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
                <td>SIN RETENCION</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
                <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
                <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
                <td>
                     <table><tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>IVA</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>120.00</td>
                            <td>100.0</td>
                            <td>120.00</td>
                       </tr>
                     </tbody></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

De todos modos, no es aconsejable tener una tabla dentro de otra tabla.

Comment: al final sugiere que no es aconsejable tener una tabla dentro de otra, que otra opcion podria utilizar?

Comment: @jeanpitx dos tablas independientes. Luego por reglas de estilo (css) puedes trabajar el código incluso para que se vean como si fuese la misma tabla. O, que sea la misma tabla, diferenciada por dos `tbody`. El problema aquí es que usas un elemento menor (un `td`) para contener un elemento superior (`table`)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar una clase a las `tr` internas o externas y usar jQuery para seleccionar.  Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("mytabla");
var fila=$("#mytabla").find('tr:not(".inner")');
console.log(fila.length);
var row=table.insertRow(parseInt(fila.length));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytabla" class="table table-sm table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th id="#">#</th>
            <th id="Documento" class="tb-gra">Documento</th>
            <th id="Fecha">Fecha(emision)</th>
            <th id="retenciones">Retenciones</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
            <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
            <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
            <td>SIN RETENCION</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
            <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
            <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
            <td>SIN RETENCION</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
            <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
            <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="inner">
                            <td>IVA</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>120.00</td>
                            <td>100.0</td>
                            <td>120.00</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se puede hacer es reemplazar la linea

```
var fila=document.getElementById("mytabla").getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

por lo siguiente:

```
var fila=document.querySelectorAll("#mytabla > tbody > tr");
```

esto efectivamente corrige el problema